# SQL Aggregate Function creation

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to create an SQL user defined aggregate function that can display a specific row from a table
that i can use in a group by query when i want to display additional data .

Assuming that i have a table called Employees which has ID , Salary , Name , Gender
when i want to display the lowest salary in both genders accompanied by their names

Select min(Salary) , **Function_name(name)** from Employees
group by Gender

**the thing is I want to try doing this without using a subquery
is that possible at all ?**

Comment: There is no subquery in your sample question, so I'm not sure what you're asking here. [User-defined Aggregates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-aggregates?view=sql-server-ver16) must be a CLR function, so they wouldn't use a subquery either. Where is the subquery you're referencing?

Comment: *"Assuming that i have a table called Employees which has ID , Salary , Name , Gender when i want to display the lowest salary in both genders accompanied by their names"* This sounds more like what you *actually* want is a [top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group).

Comment: `SELECT ID, Name, Salary, Gender FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Gender ORDER BY Salary) AS rn FROM Employees) e WHERE e.rn = 1;`